# Disabling Postfix on Ubuntu 20.04 on startup

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

How can I disable postfix/post drop during startup? If I am using a custom Ubuntu 20.04 image, is there a way to remove postfix from the default installed binaries? This is for a project I have just joined onto and so any help is appreciated.

For context, I want to disable postfix because the mail server is unused for our application, and it generates excessive warning messages to journalctl. Example warning message:

```
postfix/postdrop[3537]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/796259.3537: Read-only file system
```

For one journalctl log file, it made up 137 MB of the total 140 MB.

Comment: Very likely.  Can you edit your question with a short summary of how your custom 20.04 images are built?

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Prevent the service from starting with the OS?

Comment: @SottoVoce I'll update as soon as I find that out.

Comment: @Panki Exactly. The postfix service has been generating excessive warning messages due to /var/spool/postfix/maildrop being read-only (intentionally so). I'll edit the question with this context.

Comment: I posted an answer how to disable it - however, I'm also curious how this got into place, afaik Ubuntu doesn't come with `postfix` out of the box

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `postfix` (or any other `systemd` service) from starting with the operating system, disable it.

```
sudo systemctl disable postfix
```

See `man systemctl` for further information.

If you do not require an SMTP server at all, you might also opt to remove it along with it's configuration.

```
sudo apt purge postfix && sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: This needs to be done before the first boot using the custom Ubuntu image, hence my question (in comments) about how the custom image is built.

Comment: @SottoVoce Where is this mentioned in the OP? It mentions "during startup". see also my comment under op. I have no issue removing this answer if it doesn't even relate to OPs problem.

Comment: in the first two sentences.  If it's acceptable to not even have Postfix installed in the image, this tells me the preference is to have Postfix never even start.  I.e., disabled before startup, even though the question is worded "during startup".

Comment: I think your answer is spot on, but the steps need to be done when the image is being built, and the way to do that isn't known until Macondoman adds the image build info

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments! I could have worded the question a little better, but like Sotto Voce said, I could disable postfix using Panki's cmds when the OS is built in a preprovisioning step.